# How to enable Wi-Fi control in kiosk mode android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kiosk-mode

How to enable Wi-Fi control in kiosk mode for android. My application is registered as an admin app, If I want to switch the Wi-Fi settings, every time I'm removing the admin mode.

Is it possible to change the network settings in admin/kiosk mode?

Answer (score 0):

In Android kiosk mode, it is possible to control Wi-Fi settings with an admin app. However, you need to set the necessary permissions and use appropriate APIs to achieve this.

To enable Wi-Fi control in kiosk mode, you can use the DevicePolicyManager class, which provides APIs to manage device policies and settings, including Wi-Fi configuration. You can use the setWifiEnabled() method to enable or disable Wi-Fi, and the setWifiApEnabled() method to enable or disable Wi-Fi hotspot.

Here's an example code snippet to enable/disable Wi-Fi in kiosk mode:

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

// Check if the admin app is active
ComponentName adminComponent = new ComponentName(this, MyAdminReceiver.class);
if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponent)) {
    // Enable Wi-Fi
    devicePolicyManager.setWifiEnabled(adminComponent, true);

    // Disable Wi-Fi
    devicePolicyManager.setWifiEnabled(adminComponent, false);
}
```

Note that to use these APIs, your admin app needs to have the necessary permissions, such as android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS and android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS. Also, make sure that the app is registered as a device administrator and that the necessary policies are enabled for Wi-Fi control.

Comment: devicePolicyManager.setWifiEnabled(adminComponent, true);  This 'setWifiEnabled' method is not able to find in the DevicePolicyManager class